# Why does Git choose "git --bare init xxx" to "git init --bare xxx"?

Tags: git

IMO `--bare` is an option to Git's `init` command so it should be `git init --bare xxx`.

But why Git choose "git --bare init xxx" to "git init --bare xxx"?

Comment: Downvoting this because the OP hasn't really tried out the latter form ( which is what everyone normally uses) and asking the question as though it did not work.

Comment: @manojlds ,I tried,but it's a shame I didn't spot they're the same ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `--bare` as [an option to `git-init`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html), but `--bare` is actually also [an option you can pass to `git` itself](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/), causing it to treat the repository as a bare repository.

Comment: `git` doesn't do anything itself,it's done in the `init` command according to its source.

Comment: Passing `--bare` to `git` sets the [same configuration option](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b91766295f2b873bbd4e/git.c#L145) (in `git.c`) that [passing it to `git-init` does](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b91766295f2b873bbd4e/builtin/init-db.c#L486-487) (in `init-db.c`). Tomato, tomahto.

Comment: Yes,I'm aware of that, but why not pass it to git-init directly by `git init --bare xxx`?

Comment: +1 - @asker - Did you even try the `git init --bare` - that is the normally used form anyway!